# How to avoid dd or badblocks erasing hard drives' spare sectors?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, dd

/!\ Look for Update 2 down there, the question is half-answered now /!\

I sometimes completely wipe my hard drives (not SSDs); being what they are, `dd` and `badblocks -w` do wipe everything blindly.

The thing is, they are also writing hard drives' spare sectors, which is bad since they are all brand new.
So if something do happen during the erasure process (power loss, write errors, etc), that would kill a very useful sector... for nothing.

So the question is: How to avoid `dd` or `badblocks` erasing hard drives' spare sectors?

---

Assumptions:

- `dd` is known to blindly erase everything that goes through it.
- `badblocks` is known to be able to access unmapped blocks.

**Update 1**:

`dd` definitely can't access spare sectors if they didn't replaced a faulty sector (obviously).
This is due to how `dd` was designed (comment by Kamil Maciorowski):

> The logical sector numbers available to `dd` are mapped to numbered
>   physical sectors and the corresponding numbers are initially equal.
>   Spare physical sectors initially have no logical numbers assigned, so
>   dd cannot reach them.

**Update 2**:

Being mostly a sysadmin -and not being a "close to low-level" coder (C)-, can someone take a look at `badblocks`' code and tell if it does access spare sectors?
To be more precise, does `badblocks` also take into account spare sectors inside its block reading/writing?

http://git.kernel.org/cgit/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/tree/misc/badblocks.c

On another side/way to get the answer; I also know that Theodore Ts'o, the `badblocks`' maintainer, has an account here on Super User.
If he reads this update 2, is it possible to have a direct answer about that?

Comment: ^"I sometimes low level format my hard drives"* -- Modern ATAPI drives are not capable of low-level format.  There are only "write sector(s)" commands addressed by LBA.

Comment: How do they erase spare sectors? Those are reserved by the drive controller and not directly visible to the host... dd and other tools should have no effect on them.

Comment: As far as I know and saw on the internet (mainly stackexchange posts), dd is filling every sector available on the disk, while badblocks -w can reach unmapped sectors.

Comment: dd is indeed filling every sector available to it. The spare sectors however are not available to it.

Comment: How do spare sectors aren't available to dd ?

Comment: How aren't spare sectors available to `dd`? By design. The logical sector numbers available to `dd` are mapped to numbered physical sectors and the corresponding numbers are initially equal. Spare physical sectors initially have no logical numbers assigned, so `dd` cannot reach them. Faulty physical sector gets its logical number remapped to the spare one. Now `dd` can reach the spare, but cannot reach the faulty anymore – the total number of sectors seen by `dd` doesn't change. It's the controller job to manage the mapping. SSDs and flashdrives additionally mangle their maps to level wear.

Comment: Case closed for dd thanks to your details. :)
On the other side, do you know about those sectors being available to badblocks ? SInce it's working by blocks instead of sectors, things should be different right ?

Comment: Spare sectors are an implementation detail of a HDD. They cannot be accessed, ever. Until they become non-spare, but that's transparent. How did you even determine spare sectors are accessed?

Comment: I thought those spare sectors would get accessed since they are in the middle of the normal sectors.
For badblocks, I saw on stackexchange sites that it can access unmapped sectors.

Answer (score 8):

Neither `dd` nor `badblocks` is able to access disk hardware spare sectors.  The main reason `dd` and `badblocks` **can't** access those spare sectors is that the authors of those utils don't know how, and the proprietary nature of modern hard disk hardware and [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) software makes it prohibitively difficult to find out.

---

This Q seems to be based on a confusion between OS level file systems and disk vendor's hardware level [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) and [remapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_sector) routines.  A historical view might clarify things...

[Early PC hardware vendors](http://chmhdd.wikifoundry.com/page/Main+Timeline+of+Significant+Events+and+Products) tested disks before shipping, and included lists of bad blocks on the disk label or an included printout.  The admin who installed the drive would then perhaps use that list of bad blocks when formatting the drive.  [Early formatting programs](http://nerdlypleasures.blogspot.com/2016/05/working-with-st-506-interface-mfm-hard.html) would prompt the user for lists of bad blocks, which the user would type in by hand.   If the drive had been around a while, the admin might recheck the drive blocks.  Anyway the point of those bad block lists was to tell the [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) not to use those blocks.  The `badblocks` util seems to be designed with that sort of early hard disk in mind.

Newer hard disks include remapping routines, as well as diagnostic routines such as SMART, the both of which amount to something of a dedicated computer within the hard disk that checks for bad blocks and even remaps bad blocks, automatically.  Wonderful functionality, but what sucks about vendor remapping is that all the implementations of it are proprietary and closed source -- so users aren't sure what it's really doing, or failing to do in there.  A disk's remapping/diagnostic firmware might be buggy, there might be secret places on the disk colonized by spies or black hat hackers, etc.  Since it's disk level remapping, (not OS level), it can inefficiently cause more head thrashing and wear, (if some often used file or region is in a spot with remapped sectors).

Comment: I don’t believe SMART has any relation whatsoever with sector/block remapping. It’s just monitoring (and testing). Disks have probably had controllers (which is what you’re actually referring to) for far longer than SMART has been around. Remapping is possible without any need for reporting.

Comment: @DanielB, Thanks, I'm aware that remapping precedes SMART.  Yet somewhere I've picked up the impression that SMART did handled remapping, (or rather threw it in as a feature).  SMART definitely *reports* on remapping, (i.e. *"Reallocation Event Count"*, *"Current Pending Sector Count"*), but that isn't necessarily the same as doing the remapping itself.   Your belief is that there's a layer of code in between SMART and the hardware, and it's that in-between layer which handles remapping and perhaps other things.

Comment: @DanielB, Erroneous answers should be corrected, so I'll study this.  If you've any research pointers to help nail this "hard disk hardware>in-between layer>SMART" layering down, they'd be most welcome.

Comment: @agc SMART's long test may trigger remapping but it just politely asking internal firmware to do that. Most manufacturers won't simply give up and remap sectors at first query, firmware has internal threshold where it agree to remap badly reading sectors. As Daniel_B  pointed out SMART and remapping isn't related, we can use mhdd or Victoria to hammer badly behaving sectors until firmware agree to remap without any help from SMART.

Comment: What kind of a statement is "the authors of those utils don't know how" ? dd at least is a sophisticated program that attaches and directly calls the disk-driver. The authors surely knew enough to directly manipulate the disk if they really wanted to.

Comment: @harrymc, Re *"...calls **the** disk-driver..."*: presumably you mean a set of kernel functions or some device or other.  No kernel I'm aware of offers functions to access a drive's spare sectors.  It's not obvious why you'd suppose that knowledge of kernel calls must imply knowledge of HD hardware, especially if the latter is not widely known, (i.e. is there a single open source util that directly accesses spare sectors?).

Comment: @agc: Come on, these are *Linux developers* you are talking about. Some respect please.

Comment: @harrymc, If any Linux devs did know how to access spare sectors, and haven't released code or documented it by now, (adhering to un-Linux-ey notions of [*security through obscurity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity), or worse HD vendor [NDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement)s), that might be cause for reserving just a little respect.

Answer (score 5):

Per your request, I have taken a look at `badblocks.c` and I can testify that it
it is a very simple program that does not use any advanced disk function
and does not work on the disk-controller level.

All it does is use the Linux standard [open function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) to open the drive as a
raw device (meaning as a virtual file that includes the entire device), while
applying the `O_DIRECT` flag to do I/O directly to the disk without
going through the Linux memory buffers.

It then retrieves the number of blocks in the raw device using the
[ioctl function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html),
a number that includes only publicly visible blocks/sectors (no spare sectors),
then iterates writing and reading a pattern to each block/sector,
using the Linux standard functions of [write](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) and [read](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html),
reporting an error if any error code is returned or the data is not equal.

The open/read/write functions date from the very beginning of Linux,
when disks had a much simpler structure and no spare sectors.
Much more advanced functions would be needed to access any
internal disk data such as the spare sectors which are unavailable through casual use.

As a curiosity, the comment at the beginning of `badblocks.c` says :

```
* This file is based on the minix file system programs fsck and mkfs
* written and copyrighted by Linus Torvalds <Linus.Torvalds@cs.helsinki.fi>
```

where `Minix` pre-dated Linux ([history link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Linux)) and whose shortcomings
actually motivated Linus Torvalds to write the first version of Linux.
This is just to get an impression on how ancient and unsophisticated
is this program. It certainly does not touch the spare sectors.

I have also looked at [dd.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/base/dd.c) which is a much more sophisticated program
that attaches the disk-driver. I am not familiar with the disk-driver interface,
but it seems to me that even if the spare sectors could be modified via that
interface, no programmer in his right mind would do that. My reasons are :

1. dd can write a disk-image to and from a file, and that image does not contain
   the spare sectors (except when mapped), which probably means that dd does not touch unmapped spare sectors.
2. The spare sectors are used to remap bad sectors. Monkeying with them will mean
   that bad sectors will become unmarked and new data copied to such bad sectors may be
   corrupted and lost without notice.
3. The spare sectors mapping is unique to its disk, as two different disks can almost
   never have exactly the same defects, so copying or clearing that mapping makes no sense.

Comment: Re *"no programmer in his right mind"*:  One useful system application of spare sector access would be spare sector defragmentation, AKA [assigning slow sectors to the P-List](http://www.hddoracle.com/viewtopic.php?f=117&t=1423).  Another use would be antivirus scans, certain viruses may well be the work of deranged (or merely devious) programmers who could hide things in spare sector tables.

Comment: @agc Not very convincing. These special cases are better assigned to special programs, not to a general-purpose copy program, that to my knowledge they do not exist. And sector management is something that the disk firmware already does in its spare time, no product required.

Comment: We agree that `dd` is neither a virus scanner nor a slow G-List to P-List remapper.  Please clarify which disk firmware is capable of slow G-List to P-List remapping.